# What are some of the better open source raytracers?

Tags: open-source, graphics, raytracing

I'm just wondering what options are out there as far as open source ray tracing software. 
eg. Yafaray, POV-Ray, what else?
Any opinions on their relative merits would also be appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about software or about their source? I personally like this one: http://www.ioccc.org/2004/gavare.c

Comment: I'm more interested in actually using the software.

Comment: Would like to see some more in-depth answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POV-Ray is in my opinion the best open source **general purpose** raytracer you will find. Unless you're looking for a specific feature unavailable in POV-Ray, I can't see any reason why you wouldn't use that.

Answer (score 2):

http://mantawiki.sci.utah.edu/manta/Main_Page:
It's interactive!

http://www.pbrt.org/: It has a book!